# bcdedit.exe command giving strange error

Tags: windows, windows-10, secure-boot, bcd, bcdedit

Until yesterday i could use the command `bcdedit /set testsigning on`, so that i could start kernel mode drivers that are not signed, and then `bcdedit /set testsigning off` before shutting down, and i used this command so many times.
Suddenly, the command is now giving me the error

```
An error has occurred setting the element data.
The value is protected by Secure Boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted.
```

The true problem is that **i've always had secure boot enabled**, but bcdedit suddenly isn't fine with it anymore.
What could be causing this? I know a solution would be just to disable secure boot, but i would prefer not to do that and instaed figure out what other thing is causing this

Comment: Could there be a conflict with Group Policy, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0c233f1b-af45-4c82-8c16-50ea1a9ed76b/how-to-disable-digitally-signed-drivers-in-group-policy?forum=winserverGP ?

Comment: You shouldn't have been able to install unsigned drivers while secure boot was enabled I think.  I will ask a fellow programmer (kernel mode dev) about this.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik doing that thing with gpedit.msc didn't fix the issue

Comment: The solution to this problem is to disable Secure Boot then reenable it.  **You cannot allow unsigned device drivers and enable Secure Boot.** That being possible would defeat the purpose of Secure Boot.

Comment: Update.  Doing the above hosed the boot where bitlocker needs a recovery key.  As I said initially and @Ramhound re-iterated, you need to disable secure boot.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - That is to be expected.  BitLocker once enable will require the recovery key when ANY configuration change is made. **BitLocker also requires Secure Boot to be enabled** I have a suspicion Secure Boot wasn't actually enabled when you initially ran those commands.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - The first half of the comment was directed at you. The second was an observation, that I don't think the author had the configuration, they thought they had.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound .  I think that you are correct about everything (today anyways) ;)

Comment: then what can i do to start unsigned drivers if bcdedit testsigning is not available?

Comment: Disable secure boot?

Comment: I think i can close the question. I can just go in uefi settings and boot my laptop with disabled dse. Even if the problem isn't really solved